Macro to copy data from multiple workbooks to one master workbook
New to VBA and stack overflow. So far what I have found is very helpful but need something more detailed to my situation.
I have a solution to open all my files I need (copied) and as well close all of those files.Macro
I am having trouble copying and pasting into the destination worksheet now.
I need the open file "Macro tab" information copied into the mast file for all of my open files.Input information
Sub CP()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long


  Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("WATERFALL TEST IDEA.xlsx").Worksheets("Output")
    
  
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
 
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro").Range("A1:E5").Copy
  
  
   Workbooks("WATERFALL TEST IDEA.xlsx").Worksheets("Output").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Workbooks("WATERFALL TEST IDEA.xlsx").Worksheets("Output").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    
    
End Sub

This is what I have so far, it works from the regular file pasted into the master workbook. But I need the master workbook to open these files, copy & paste, close files.

Please post existing code as text - not as an image.

I would suggest placing the macro code within the destination workbook and change it to something like this:
strFile = "the workbook name to be copied from.xlsx"
nextRow = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Output").Cells(Rows.Count, 
1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Workbooks(strFile).Worksheets("Macro").Range("A1:E5").Copy _
 Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Output").Range("A" & nextRow)


Thanks for the response! The only issue is there will be multiple excel files open from that range with the tab name "Macro" that I need copied and pasted to the one "master" file. I also will need it to paste down one row from the already pasted data in the workbook. I appreciate all the help! :)

You should be able to update strFile with the workbook name for each pass, to make sure it's looking at the correct one.  I've updated the code above to adjust how the copy/paste function works, to make sure it pastes new values 1 row down from existing values.
